# Get all layerIds or groups from leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there a function hidden somewhere to retrieve all the the layerIds or Groups currently available on a leaflet map?  I'm pretty sure this would be fairly easy using the javascript interface, but I haven't found a solution using the R leaflet API.

The context is a shiny app where layers can be added, successively.  I was debating maintaining a reactiveValues and update it with each group/layerId when appropriate, but it ends up being a bunch of extra coding/observers.  Is there a function or simple way to get the groups or layerIds, or even better both?

Comment: Indeed in vanilla JavaScript you could have simply used a Layer Group as "proxy", adding all your other layers into it instead of the map, then use [getLayers()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayers). Some controls and plugins would still directly add to the map though.

Comment: @pickle rick - did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @nate not that I recall, but its been years since I used shiny/leaflet

Answer (score 3):

If you have a map

```
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
    addPopups(-122.327298, 47.597131, content, layerId = "my layer id",
              options = popupOptions(closeButton = TRUE)
    )
```

Then you can get the layerId from

```
m$x$calls[[2]]$args[[4]]

[1] "my layer id"
```

For a more general map m with multiple layerIds and groups introduced with multiple methods (such as addMarkers, addCircles, etc) try using

```
l <- lapply(lapply(m$x$calls, function(x) x[[2]]), function(x) x[4][[1]])
layerIds <- unlist(l[sapply(l, function(x) {class(x) != "list" & !is.null(x)})])

g <- lapply(lapply(m$x$calls, function(x) x[[2]]), function(x) x[5][[1]])
groupIds <- unlist(g[sapply(g, function(x) {class(x) != "list" & !is.null(x)})])
```

Comment: does this work if you use a leaflet proxy inside a shiny app?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `eachLayer` method of `L.Map` to iterate the layers:

> Iterates over the layers of the map, optionally specifying context of the iterator function.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-eachlayer

Comment: this would be great, but cant figure out how to do it in R.  Anyway +1, Ill probably have to use javascript I suppose.