# Is there a function in R for leaflet that does the same thing as eachLayer() in leaflet for javascript?

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I am trying to get the layerIDs from all markers currently displayed on my leaflet map in my Shiny app.
The Problem is that the map is constantly being updated using leafletProxy during a simulation and at the start of each new loadstep, I would like to know what layerIds have already been plotted.

```
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%

    leafletProxy(mapId = "m", 
                 data = data_1) %>%
    addMarkers(lng = 1, lng = 2, layerId = "Marker_1")

    leafletProxy(mapId = "m", 
                 data = data_2) %>%
    addMarkers(lng = 1, lng = 2, layerId = "Marker_2")
```

A useful function exists for leaflet in javascript, but I couldn't find it's counterpart in R: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-eachlayer

The solution proposed by Vlad ([Get all layerIds or groups from leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460597/get-all-layerids-or-groups-from-leaflet)) does not work for this specific case, since I am using the leafletProxy function to update the map.

```
l <- lapply(lapply(m$x$calls, function(x) x[[2]]), function(x) x[4][[1]])
layerIds <- unlist(l[sapply(l, function(x) {class(x) != "list" & !is.null(x)})])
```